# Sending mail with base64 image atttachment using PHPmailer

Tags: php, base64, phpmailer

What is the proper setup to send an email with the image attached to it?.

I created a function for my `include.php` to get all the details to send using phpmailer:

```
function send_mail($args){  
require_once('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer(true); 
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->Port       = 25;
$mail->Host = "localhost";

$mail->Username = 'myusername';
$mail->Password = "*************";

$mail->From = "name@company.com";
$mail->FromName = "Notification"; 

$mail->Subject = $args['subject'];
$mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!';
$mail->AddStringAttachment($args['base64-attachment']);

$mail->MsgHTML($args['content']);

  if(strpos($args['to']['email'], ',')){
    $recipients = explode(',',$args['to']['email']);
    foreach($recipients as $v) $mail->AddAddress(trim($v), $args['to']['name']);  
  }else{
      $mail->AddAddress($args['to']['email'], $args['to']['name']);
  }

try {
  $mail->Send();
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {

} catch (Exception $e) {

}   
}
```

`message.php` file

```
    $imgdata = '...';//base64 image here
    $args['to']['name'] = 'John Smith';
    $args['to']['email'] = 'johnsmith@company.com';

    $args['content'] = 'Image attached!';
    $args['from']['email'] = 'mail@company.com';
    $args['from']['name'] = 'Company name';
    $args['subject'] = 'Image';

    $args['base64-attachment'] = ($imgdata, 'Contract.png', 'base64', 'image/png'); //error with this line

    send_mail($args);
```

This won't send the mail and the attachment. Can someone help me? Thank you!

Comment: No errors displayed?

Comment: @hungrykoala The only error is `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' ..on line 149` And this is the line I think.. `$args['base64-attachment'] = ($imgdata, 'Contract.png', 'base64', 'image/png');`

Comment: I would check what's on line 149 and why does it have a `,`

Comment: Why is it formatted that way? Do you have something in mind?

Comment: @hungrykoala I have to pass the values for `AddStringAttachment` function which is `public function AddStringAttachment($string, $filename, $encoding = 'base64', $type = 'application/octet-stream') {....
  }`

Comment: Will it always be a base64 image?

Comment: yes, it is always be a base64 image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
$args['base64-attachment'] = ($imgdata, 'Contract.png', 'base64', 'image/png');
```

To this:

```
$args['base64-image']      = $imgdata;
$args['base64-attachment'] = "Contract.png, base64, image/png";
```

And we're gonna update this:

```
$mail->AddStringAttachment($args['base64-attachment']);
```

to this:

```
$attach_parameter = explode(",", $args['base64-attachment']);
$mail->AddStringAttachment($args['base64-image'], $attach_parameter[0], $attach_parameter[1], $attach_parameter[2]);
```

Or if it will always be a base64 image then you can just do it like this:
You can also make `Contract.png` as a variable instead

```
$mail->AddStringAttachment($args['base64-image'], 'Contract.png', 'base64', 'image/png');
```

You can't just pass this `($imgdata, 'Contract.png', 'base64', 'image/png')` directly as a parameter since the function will expect multiple variable as a parameter.

Comment: Thank you for helping me and for the detailed explanation as well.

Comment: I don't know why you are base64-encoding the data yourself - PHPMailer does that for you, so providing data in base64 will result in double encoding. If you want to attach binary data (like a PNG file), pass in binary data and PHPMailer will deal with it, including base64-encoding it appropriately.